# Conditional join using sqldf in R with time data

Tags: sql, r, join, sqldf

So I have a have a table (~2000 rows, call it df1) of when a particular subject received a medication on a particular date, and I have a large excel file (>1 million rows) of weight data for subjects for different dates (call it df2).

**AIM**: I want to group by subject and find the weight in df2 that was recorded closest to the medication admin time in df1 using sqldf(because tables are too big to load into R). Or alternatively, I can set up a time frame of interest (e.g. +/- 1 week of medication given) and find a row that falls within that timeframe.

Example:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(
  PtID = rep(c(1:5), each=2),
  Dose = rep(seq(100,200,25),2),
  ADMIN_TIME =seq.Date(as.Date("2016/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 10)
)

 df2 <- data.frame(
   PtID = rep(c(1:5),each=10),
   Weight = rnorm(50, 50, 10),
   Wt_time = seq.Date(as.Date("2016/01/01"), as.Date("2016/10/31"), length.out = 50)
 )
```

So I think i want to left_join df1 and df2, group by PtID, and set up some condition that identifies either the closest df2$Weight to the df1$Admin_time or a df2$Weight within an acceptable range around df1$Admin_time using sql formatting.

So I tried creating a range and then querying the following:

```
library(dplry)
library(lubridate)
 df1 <- df1 %>% 
   mutate(ADMIN_START = ADMIN_TIME - ddays(30),
          ADMIN_END = ADMIN_TIME + ddays(30))

#df2.csv is the large spreadsheet saved in my working directory
 result <- read.csv.sql("df2.csv", sql = "select Weight from file
                left join df1
                on file.Wt_time between df1.ADMIN_START and df1.ADMIN_END")
```

This will run but it never results anything and I have to escape out of it. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: lookup fuzzy join https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin and this post https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881

Comment: *large excel file (>1 million rows)* -really? Excel files limit is around ~1 mill (exactly 2^20).

Comment: There have been many [R join by time range](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+join+by+range) questions asked on StackOverflow. Please search, give it a try and return with any specific issues showing your earnest efforts.

Comment: I've searched through the StackOverflow posts and haven't found any that overlap well with what I'm specifically looking for.  I know about fuzzy join, but I'm hoping to avoid loading the tables into R because of their size.  So I am trying to accomplish it using SQL syntax with the sqlfdf package.  The syntax of the conditional SQL selection with grouping function is what I was hoping to receive assistance with. I'm not sure why the skepticism about my row number.  I have 1,048,002 rows if an exact count satisfies your curiosity. I also have 3 of those and about 12 others with >100k rows.